# Show a form at specific parameter value

Tags: python, django, forms

I was wondering: is it possible to return an object when a parameter is true? I have multiple forms in django, and i want to show `Form1` when the parameter in the url is set to `1`. It won't work for now when i do this:

```
def get_form(request, step):
if parameter == 1:
form = get_form_form1(request)
return HttpResponse(form)
```

`get_form_form1(request)` is defined like a normal form script, returning a template.

EDIT

```
def get_form_form1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ObjectForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            object = Object()
            object.project_project = Project.objects.get(pk=object.id).values('project_id')
            o = form.save()
            o.save()
            url = reverse('opname:get_form', kwargs={'form_id': 2})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = ObjectForm1()
    return render(request, 'opname/home.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Did you try `request.GET.get('param-name')` ?

Comment: It gave an error

Comment: I cant guess it !

Comment: Well, i hope you can help me. I tried the answer beneath, it gave the `Unresolved referece` error, while var form was declared in the IF statement.

Comment: @AugustinLaville

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

The string was passed as an **string** in the url. The fact is: I declared it as an integer in the if-statement.

**Solution**

Dont do this:
`if form_id == 1` but this: `if form_id == '1'`.

That's the way to go